# Using CNN/NN for text classification and extraction of data from text

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification, fuzzy-search

So I have this data of house addresses and house numbers(1 to N) where the house addresses are @1house/city in most of the places, i.e we can distinguish 2 houses by the city and place/street name mostly and need not use the door number to distinguish.

I have the data of all the house addresses -  Number mapping for training.

Now if I am given the description of a person which is very scrambled text with the house address as a part of the text, I should be able to map the person to the house number. 
classify : Mc Donalds buffet          OLATHE       KS~~XXX~XXXXXX~XXXXX1112
trained on : 15/31 oakwood street, OLATHE, kentucky state, KS, south lane.

Now since the neural net is trained on the address - house number mapping, I want to create a neural network with N output nodes and use the training data(N points with 1 address as training sample for 1 output node).

Will the size of the training data set suffice ? Is there any other better approach rather than using CNN on this? (Will update the question if more details are required)